# PHP below other PHP not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this PHP Wordpress Loop which is getting articles from a tag

```
<?php
// Fetch all posts relating to a certain tag then display 4 of them
$args = array('numberposts' => 4, 'tag_slug__and' => array('tomb-raider'));
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
    ?>
  <?php
//Get the Thumbnail URL
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 720,405 ),     false, '' );
    ?>
  <li class="promo-list-item" style="background-image: url(' <?php echo $src[0];?> '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"> </li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

For some reason having this on the webpages causes all the other PHP below it to stop working. Removing this code makes the other PHP work again.

Also do you know a way of getting using a tag attached to a post as the tag to search for in the tag-slug array? Trying to get it more dynamic than having to manually enter a tag slug.

Comment: Sounds like there's a php fatal error, have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Checked the logs and any error messages not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

Just for others that might have the same issue.

I forgot to reset the post data using this  at the end of the loop after the .

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the `;` at the end of your last `endforeach` statement.

Probably causing an error.

Comment: Added that but the php below this php is still not outputting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Fetch all posts relating to a certain tag then display 4 of them

$args = array('numberposts' => 4,'tag_slug__in' => array('tomb-raider'));
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 
720,405 ),false, '' );
echo '<li class="promo-list-item" style="background-image: 
url("'.$src[0].'"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"> 
</li>';

endforeach; ?>
```